# Did I award the bounty?

Tags: support, specific-question, bounty

I recently put a bounty on this question:

[Prove isometry preserving excision is Killing-like?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/341968/)

and Valter Moretti answered it just before it expired (I think). I took the weekend to consider his answer and accepted yesterday (Monday, July 10) and don't recall seeing an award bounty button. Valter may not have received the bounty - I can't tell. How do I ensure he receives/received his just reward - which I thought I had awarded.

Answer (score 3):

No, it appears that the [bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/209806) was not awarded. This is only possible to do before the grace period ends.

Comment: But if i recall correctly, it should automatically go to the accepted answer if there is one if the bounty offerer does not take explicit action. If he has not and will not receive the bounty, can I directly donate the same amount of rep to him - especially if the fault is mine!

Comment: @JulianMoore If his answer had had 2+ votes at the end of the grace period, then it would have received half of the bounty. However, it doesn't look like that was the case here.

Comment: @HDE226868 Not the whole bounty, only half of it.

Comment: @peterh Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Whilst I note that @Alfred-Centauri has also added a bounty I would like to acknowledge the answerer's effort & my error (see latest comment by me to the answer) and want to add a further bounty of 50 of my own but I do not see how to do that (no more bounty button?) Advice appreciated.

Comment: @JulianMoore You can't start a bounty on a question with a currently active bounty. Also, on questions you already have offered a bounty on before, you must offer at least double the amount you have offered before, so you won't be able to offer 50 as a bounty on this particular question even after the current bounty has run its course.

Comment: @acuriousmind Thanks. I will put 100 on when the current bounty expires: the answers are well worth it!